# Does $M^\beta\subseteq M$ imply $M_\beta = V_\beta$?

Tags: logic, set-theory

Suppose $V$ is the universe and $\kappa$ is supercompact, let $\beta>\kappa$. Then there are $M$ and $j$ such that $[M]^\beta\subseteq M$ and $j:V\prec M$ with $crit(j)=\kappa$ and $j(\kappa)>\beta$. ($j$ elementary. $[M]^\beta$ is ‘the collection of all $\beta$-sequences of elements of $M$’.)

In this situation it is apparently true that $M_\beta =V_\beta$, but I am not able to see why. I imagine it is pretty simple, but please take me out of my misery.

This is the lemma:

[image: New proofs of the consistency of the normal Moore space conjecture I]

Screenshot from: [New proofs of the consistency of the normal Moore space conjecture I.](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/016686419090013R)

Comment: By "$M_\beta$" do you mean $(V_\beta)^M$, that is, the thing $M$ thinks is the $\beta$th level of the cumulative hierarchy?

Comment: What do you mean by $[M]^\beta$? The notation is usually understood as the collection of subsets of $M$ of order-type $\beta$, but then you need to specify under what ordering (membership?). Or perhaps you mean the collection of subsets of $M$ of cardinality $|\beta|$? Or $M^\beta$, the collection of functions $f\!:\beta\to M$? In any case, the result is false in general under the last two interpretations. Or do you have additional requirements on $\beta$?

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo It is the set of sequences of elements of $M$. There doesn’t seem to be any other requirements on $\beta$; I’ve added some images from the paper, as I must be missing something. (The paper is New proofs of the consistency of the normal Moore space conjecture, by Dow, Tall, and Weiss.)

Comment: @NoahSchweber By $M_\beta$ it is meant the sets in $M$ of rank less than $\beta$. I believe it is equivalent to what you’re saying, as rank is an absolute notion.

Comment: There's an option to put a citation in your question. You can even search for the paper using keywords (e.g. authors and partial title). Use that feature, please, and include an accurate citation to the paper from which these screenshots were taken.

Comment: The paper doesn't say that any $\beta$-supercompact embedding has the property, only that some such embedding does. The proof could be phrased better, since it is not quite correct as written. For a correct argument, start for example with a $\lambda$-supercompact embedding for $\lambda$ so large that indeed $M_\beta=V_\beta$. To see that as written things don't quite work, note that if $\kappa$ is measurable and $j\!:V\to M$ is an ultrapower embedding, then $M^{\kappa+2}\subset M$ but $V_{\kappa+2}$ contains all ultrafilters on $\kappa$ while $M$ doesn't.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo  Do you mean that given any $\beta$ I can find a $\lamda$ large enough so that $[M]^\lambda\subseteq M$ implies $M_\beta = V_\beta$, or is there something else at play?

Comment: Yes, exactly, but really, do not use $[M]^{\lambda}$ (in spite of the paper). The correct notation is $M^\lambda$, and the square brackets mean something different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$M^\beta\subseteq M$ does not imply $M_\beta=V_\beta$.

However, for a given $\beta$ you can find $\lambda$ large enough so that $M^\lambda\subseteq M$ implies $M_\beta = V_\beta.$

(And this is enough for the present purpose, which is to find for a fixed $\beta$ a supercompact embedding and a class $M$ with $j:V\rightarrow M$ and $V_\beta=M_\beta$ and $M^\beta\subseteq M.$)

For fixed $\beta$, let $$\lambda=\bigcup\{|x|\mid x\in V_\beta\}.$$
Suppose $M^\lambda\subseteq M$ and suppose by contradiction that $V_\beta\setminus M_\beta$ is non-empty and let $x\in V_\beta\setminus M_\beta$ be $\in$-minimal.

By choice of $x$ and definition of $\lambda$ we have $x\subseteq M_\beta$ and $|x|\leq\lambda.$ As $M^\lambda\subseteq M$, this implies $x\in M$. But rank$(x)<\beta$ gives $x\in M_\beta$ which contradicts choice of $x$.

This is based on Andrés Caicedo's comment but there were a couple of details to fill in.